# Save created record to DB failed

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Basically, entity framework 4.5, c# 4.0. Sql Server 2008.

I was going to creat new records and insert them to the table but when I checked the database nothing changed. Why?

```
public DbSet<IxDetails> IxDetailRecords { get; set; }
IxContext ixContext = new IxContext();

var list = (from Ix in ixContext.IxDetailRecords
                   select Ix).ToList();
for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++)
{
       IxDetails ix = ixContext.IxDetailRecords.Create();
       ix.EnteredBy = "";// current user;
       ix.EntryDate = DateTime.Now;
       ix.FacilityID = facility;
       ix.FirstName = "";
       list.Add(ix);
 }
 ixContext.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public DbSet<IxDetails> IxDetailRecords { get; set; }
IxContext ixContext = new IxContext();

for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++)
{
       IxDetails ix = ixContext.IxDetailRecords.Create();
       ix.EnteredBy = "";// current user;
       ix.EntryDate = DateTime.Now;
       ix.FacilityID = facility;
       ix.FirstName = "";
       ixContext.IxDetailRecords.Add(ix);
 }
 ixContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Rick beat me to this but I was going to recommend the same.  The key is you need to add the record to the Context -- you're simply adding to a List<OfYourItem> which is not tracked by your context.

Comment: (didn't mean to hijack, just wanted to make sure he got the answer)

Comment: No worries, answer is what matters.

Comment: Why do you still have the query in there? It can be removed entirely.

Comment: Are you using EF Code First? If so, can you update your post to include your IxContext class?

Answer (score 0):

You were adding the items to the list returned in the results, not to the actual collection that represents the database query.

If you look at the methods of `ixContext.IxDetailRecords` you should see an `Attach` method (or something along those lines, depending on the provider).  Use that to attach the newly created item to the database context.

Comment: @Love You don't need to create the list at all, just remove that section, and use `ixContext.IxDetailRecords.Attach` right where you are currently using `Add` to add it to the list.  If I just give you code to copy/paste then you'll be in the exact same position the next time something comes up.  Read through the answer; think critically about what it means, experiment on your own, look through the relevant documentation/intellisense, and if you still have problems comment indicating what they are and what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Code first method would look like this:

```
public class YourDatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<IxDetails> IxDetailRecords { get; set; }
}

public class DataLoader
{    
    public void AddRecords()
    {
        using (var db = new YourDatabaseContext())
        {
            var newRecord = new IxDetailRecord {... };
            db.IxDetailRecords.Add(newRecord);
            db.Save();
        }
    }
}
```